# context-sensitive behaviour of editor

Tags: editors

I would like to have a free editor under linux which has context-sensitive behaviour: When I am in an itemize-enivronment (i.e. between a `\begin{itemize}` and a `\end{itemize}`) I want the editor to start every new line with `\item`. Is there such an editor?

Comment: By "new line" I mean "\n", a hard line break.

Comment: In Kile, ctrl + return does this, but return does not. I think this is more useful, personally.

Answer (score 1):

That really isn't useful, my `\item`s often are several lines long.

That said, I use `xemacs` with AUC-TeX, it has meny commands tailored to LaTeX, e.g. `C-c C-j` in a list environment gives an `\item`. I understand `GNU emacs` does the same, and I believe `vim` is also programmable and has special commands for LaTeX, but I'm not familiar with that one.

There probably are others, perhaps look around in Linux fora.